# How to set JDK_HOME

Tags: java, environment-variables, snap-python

I try to work with the snappy module in python using conda as a virtuelenv. I have in Linux Mint 18 Sarah.

I have the module `snappy`, but if i try to test it with the following code: `from snappy import ProductIO` I got the following response:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/mara/.snap/snap-python/snappy/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    import jpyutil
ImportError: No module named 'jpyutil'
```

Thus, I tried to get jdk with `pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/pypi/simple jpy` . And i got: `Error: Environment variable "JDK_HOME" must be set to a JDK (>= v1.6) installation directory`

Thus, I installed `jdk1.8.0_111`. I used this instruction: https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1372. But I don't know how to set the JDK_HOME variable in a correct way. I tried it using an instruction for JAVA_HOME (https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java) and write `JDK_HOME="/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_111"` in the environment file but it doesn't work. I got the same Error like before changing the environment file.

Hope somebody can help me.

Comment: check this link, i think the same to ubuntu as well

https://douglascayers.com/2015/05/30/how-to-set-custom-java-path-after-installing-jdk-8/

Comment: this is a instruction for windows. and i read/posted an instruction for mint/ubuntu for JAVA_HOME.

Comment: may be this might works for you

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qlT0T9NjKZ4

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I set JAVA_HOME like the video told me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a symbolic link:

```
ln -s /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_111 /opt/java/latest
```

Directory listing for `/opt/java`:

```
.
jdk1.8.0_111/
latest/ -> /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_111
```

Set exports

```
export JDK_HOME=/opt/java/latest
export JAVA_HOME=${JDK_HOME}
export PATH=$PATH:${JAVA_HOME}/bin
```

Now, when you install a new version of the Java JDK, simply alter your *latest* symbolic link.

Comment: Ok. It solves the problem, but I get a new error.  
`Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-p2voq_f8/jpy/setup.py", line 100, in <module>
        with open('README.rst') as file:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.rst' `

Comment: Just Google: [***FileNotFoundError setup.py module README.rst***](https://www.google.com/search?q=FileNotFoundError+setup.py+module+README.rst). Your new issue is not related to your installation. Java is irrelevant at this point.